# I am trying to Get Bounding Box of each text using Tesseract Engine but some word overlap when set it front side

Tags: c#, jquery, tesseract, bounding-box, bounding

I am trying to Get Bounding Box of each text using Tesseract Engine then all text set according bounding In DIV tag using SPAN tag but some word overlap

Here i am attached screenshot for what am trying.
**Get All Text Boundings using Tesseract Engine**
Get All Text Boundings using Tesseract Engine c# (https://i.stack.imgur.com/V06Rl.png)
And also attached screenshot for how i am set word front side.
****Set Taxt at front side using Jquery**
Set Taxt at front side using Jquery (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJucl.png)
****Here my Output**
[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bhcU.png)

here attached my required output screenshot.
[Required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T7sW.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.